# Check form for changes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an HTML page built using AngularJS. The page has a form containing a number of fields.
I have a Save, Back and Cancel button. When you click the back button I would like to be able to tell if changes have been made to the field and prompt the question "Would you like to save your changes?".
If you click the Cancel button, I want to ignore any changes made and go back to the previous page. How can this be achieved in Angular?

Comment: Have you applied your efforts for the requirement? You should place your efforts.

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?... And try to take a look at the help pages for $scope.$watch. Also you would probably want to hook the navigation events.

Comment: A form controller has a $pristine flag. Use it to know if any form component has been used by the user.

Answer (score 0):

fYou can use "$locationChangeStart" https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newURL) {
        if (newURL.lastIndexOf("#/") >= 0) {
            $scope.locationToMove = newURL.substring(newURL.lastIndexOf("#/") + 1); // here you can store the location to move for future use
        } else {
            $scope.locationToMove = "/";
        }
        if ($scope.form.$dirty && !goToBack && !saved) {
            $scope.displayConfirmationModel = true; // any alerts you want to show here
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            // you can move to that location
        }
    });
```

In the if you can check any change condition , its just for example I have given. You can do this for any location change , but if you want to do this on cancel or back button then you can have the same condition on the button click method and check for change .i.e if the form filed is dirty.